# What is the intuition behind Coppock curve?

Tags: time-series, discrete-time

[Coppock curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppock_curve) is defined as the following:

$$z_{k+1} = Coppock = WMA[10] \; of \; (ROC[14] + ROC[11])$$

where $ROC[14]$ is percentage rate of change of the current value of input $s$ with respect to the one that is 14 steps behind, i.e.,

$$
ROC[14] = x_{k+1}=100\frac{s_k-s_{k-14}}{s_{k-14}}
$$
Similarly,
$$
ROC[11] = y_{k+1}=100\frac{s_k-s_{k-11}}{s_{k-11}}
$$
and $WMA[10]$ is the weighted moving average for a window including 10 values, i.e.,

$$
z_{k+1}=\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{10}i}\sum_{i=1}^{10} 1\times(x_{k-10}+y_{k-10})+2\times(x_{k-9}+y_{k-9})+\dots+10\times(x_{k+1}+y_{k+1})
$$

Note that the above is valid when we have access to 14 previous values of $s$.
My questions:

1- Coppock curve is supposed to catch the lowest or highest of the curve, why its setup makes it possible to do that?

2- Instead of $14$, $11$, or $10$ we can go with any integers? What would be the effect of changing them?

Comment: In the link you provided, it says "He(Coppock) thought market downturns were like bereavements and required a period of mourning. He asked the church bishops how long that normally took for people, their answer was 11 to 14 months and so he used those periods in his calculation." Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Noah Tang: Unfortunately no. I want to see why this works algebraically. Since it is a metric that is use by people. I want to know why the new time series $z_{k+1}$ is capable of prediction.

Comment: If it works it's due to psychology, not math.

Comment: @JonathanZ supports MonicaC: by changing constants 14 and 11 we can apply this to another $s$ which does not follow the pattern inspiring Coppeck to derive his. ROC's are taking derivative and moving average smooth them out.